# install pear packages from github

Tags: php, pear

I have an old project that relies heavily on PEAR. I need to run the script that installs pear packages daily on a clean virtual machine. In other words, I have to install packages daily since it's a new vm everyday.

Now that PEAR is down and there is no ETA, I can't instal from php.pear.net

My question is how to install pear packages now that pear server is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the zip you need from https://github.com/pear/ for example: https://github.com/pear/Pager and then pear install package.xml

Unfortunately, this is a terrible solution and it remains to wait until the party gets up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that for multiple packages I use (HTTP, Archive_Tar, MDB2 ..) but I always get ``No valid packages found install failed``

Comment: I also tried ``pear package package.xml`` then ``pear intall`` the generated file. I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/setup-pear-and-install-pear-packages/ but in download package directory?

Answer (score 0):

I tried install package pear Pager in this way:
Download zip from github -> in console I went to the downloaded folder -> I used the command: sudo pear install package.xml
then Pager is installed, but with many package this is very problematic... 
I got info from another dev that I have to wait for the website to get up, but it has been going on for so long...